# Does Mathematica have that function which returns the variables back

Tags: functions, variable

Does Mathematica have this function where I can give a system of equations as an input and the function return back to me the variables which were included in that system. For example:

input Function[x+2y+3z^2==5]
expected output is x,y,z

Or:

input Function[u+2sin[v]+3z^2==5]
expected output is u,v,z

Is there any function does such kind of things?

Comment: Yes it works for one single eqn, but for the system of eqns does [[1]] will change ?

Comment: expr = {x + 2 y + 3 z^2 == 5 , u + v == 2}
 Variables@expr[[1]]

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**

Thanks @BobHanlon

```
Clear[function,eqns]; 
function = Variables[Level[#, {-1}]] &;
eqns = {u + 2 Sin[v] + 3 z^2 == 5, x + 2 Sin[x] + 3 z^2 == 5};
function[eqns]
```

> `{u, z, v, x}`

**Original**

```
eqn = u + 2 Sin[v] + 3 z^2 == 5;
Variables /@ Level[eqn, {-1}] // Flatten
```

> `{u, z, v}`

```
function = Flatten[Variables /@ Level[#, {-1}]] &
function[u + 2 Sin[v] + 3 z^2 == 5]
```

> `{u, z, v}`

Comment: What if we have system of eqns,
eqn = {u + 2 Sin[v] + 3 z^2 == 5, x + 2 Sin[x] + 3 z^2 == 5};

Comment: @MathView  Updated.

Comment: Or just `Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks!

Comment: Like here 
Clear[function, eqns];
function = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Variables /@ Level[#, {-1}]]] &;
eqns = {u[1] + 2 Sin[u[2]] + 3 u[3]^2 == 5, 
   u[4] + 2 Sin[u[5]] + 3 u[6]^2 == 5};
function[eqns]

Comment: @MathView - for the example with indexed variables `Cases[eqns, _u, Infinity]` Or if there are duplicates add `// Union` at the end.

Comment: here the code doesn't work 

eqn = {u[1, 2] + 2 Sin[u[1, 1]] + 3 u[1, 4]^2 == 5, x + y == 5};
Variables /@ Level[eqn, {-1}] // Flatten

the output it should be 
u[1,2],u[1,1],u[1,4],x,y

Comment: @MathView You shold ask a new question!

Comment: It seems like there is an extra bracket in Variables[Level[#, {-1}]] that leads to syntax error

Comment: @userrandrand Fixed, Thanks.